# JS: get x amount of random numbers inside interval with while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm working on a card game with six available suits, but there can be 2-6 players and I only want the number of suits to match the amount of players.

```
let players = 4    
const suits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Of course, I want them to come out randomly.

I have come up with the following solution:

```
export function getRandomSuits(nrOfPlayers) {
    const rangeMin = 1;
    const rangeMax = 6;
    const amount = nrOfPlayers;
    let nums = [];

    let getRandomNumber = function() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * rangeMax) + rangeMin);
    }

    while (nums.length < amount) {
        let nr = getRandomNumber();
        var numberExists = _.indexOf(nums, nr);
        console.log(numberExists);
        if(numberExists < 0) {
            nums.push(nr);
        }
    }

    return nums;
}
```

It's been a while since I used the "while loop" thingy, so I'm not feeling very comfortable with it.

My questions are:

1. Is this good practice or is there a better solution?
2. Are there any performance or other practical reasons why this solution is bad?
3. Am I overthinking it?

Comment: You shouldn’t define a function within a function

Comment: Why?, I've seen it in lots of places.

Comment: Your `while` technique is a good idea, but the number of iterations it will take to find X different numbers is random. It could theorically be infinite, if, for example, there's only one available suit, and it keeps hitting other numbers. You could control that by using a temporary Array where you list all available suits, and once you pick one, remove it from that Array. That way, you'll never hit the same suit twice (more efficient).

Comment: @Hum4n01d Why? There's nothing wrong with that. Arguably, it's better if you figure you'll never use the function anywhere else. That way, you're not polluting the namespace. I do it in Clojure all the time if I need a helper function, but will only need it for 1 function. The OP's use of nested functions here isn't necessary, but I wouldn't say never to do it.

Comment: It's best good practice to define things in the narrowest scope necessary.

Comment: Tx @blex, that is just the kind of answer I was looking for. Not quite sure what you mean with the temporary array though... do you mean that I should do it sort of backward, where I use a for loop on the temp array and remove suits from it until it is empty? Getting myself a little confused :/

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ok I guess that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In my opinion, I see no need of the function `getRandomNumber()`. Nonetheless, this is up to preference. 
   I would go with:

   ```
   export function getRandomSuits(nrOfPlayers) {
       const rangeMin = 1;
       const rangeMax = 6;
       let nums = [];

       while (nums.length < nrOfPlayers) {
           let nr = Math.floor((Math.random() * rangeMax) + rangeMin);
           var numberExists = _.indexOf(nums, nr);
           if(numberExists < 0) {
               nums.push(nr);
           }
       }

       return nums;
   }
   ```
2. Not necessarily. Merely a matter of cleanliness and preference.
3. Maybe? :-)

Second method (Slightly better) with a temporary array:

```
export function getRandomSuits(nrOfPlayers) {

    const rangeMin = 1;
    const rangeMax = 6;
    var tempNum = [];
    for(i = 0; i <= rangeMax - rangeMin; i++){
        tempNum[i] = rangeMin + i;
    }
    let nums = [];
    while (nums.length < nrOfPlayers) {
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempNum.length);
        var numberExists = _.indexOf(nums, tempNum[index]);
        if(numberExists < 0) {
            nums.push(tempNum[index]);
            tempNum.splice(tempNum, index));
        }
    }

    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up :) if you want you can remove the little console.log as well ;) I used the inner function because I was playing around with the randomizer and it was prettier when it was outside of the while-loop.

Comment: do you understand what blex means by using a temporary array?

Comment: Yes. The problem he mentioned is that you will hit the same number more than once. To prevent that he suggests a temporary array. I will try and add an implementation of that method.

Comment: @Winter I have added a second implementation which goes along the lines of what blex was mentioning.

Comment: hello again, I did not have time to really test this until now, but there is a typo at the line where you splice tempNum, I think is should be tempNum.splice(index, 1);

Comment: also, after further experimenting it would seem that numberExists is unneccesary since as far as I can tell it will always be true. Is that correct?